# terraform count index and length

Tags: azure, terraform

Trying to create multiple private DNS zone

1. non prod --> Dev,QA,UAT.
2. prod     --> Prd,DR

Resource should be created only if is_nonprod is set to 1. *emphasized text*(boolean value).
Idea is to use count twice in resource block : once for boolean and once for length function.

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
      
      count                  = var.is_nonprod ? 1 : 0 && length(var.env)
      name                   = var.env[count.index].npr
      resource_group_name    = "examplerg"
    }
```

variable file:

```
variable "env" {
  description = "List of routes to be added to the route table"
  default     = []
  type        = list(map(any))
}

variable "is_nonprod " {
    default = true
}
```

tfvars

```
env = [
  { npr = "qa" },
  { npr = "uat" },
  { npr = "dev" }
]
```

Error :
*The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
expressions are number and bool, respectively.*

workaround :

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
      
      count                  = var.is_nonprod ? 1 : 0 
      count                  = length(var.env)
      name                   = var.env[count.index].npr
      resource_group_name    = "examplerg"
    }
```

Error :
*The argument "count" was already set at main.tf:96,3-8. Each argument may be
set only once.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var.is_nonprod ? 1 : 0 && length(var.env)` does not look like the logic you want here based on what you described in the question. It seems like you really want `var.is_nonprod ? length(var.env) : 0`, which is also syntactically valid. The `&&` operator inputs and returns booleans, which are not valid as an input type to the `count` metaparameter. `count` takes a number as input (typically the number of resources you want to manage), and not `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like datatype conflicts. You can directly use `count = var.is_nonprod ?  length(var.env) : 0`  and it should give you expected results.